# Getting snapshot cost based on tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to use the cost explorer API using boto3. I am trying to get cost for EC2 snapshots. These snapshots have custom tags associated with them. What I am trying to retrieve is the cost of snapshots which have a particular tag.

I have written the following script:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ce')
response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={
        'Start': '2019-01-20',
        'End': '2019-01-24'
    },
    Metrics=['BLENDED_COST','USAGE_QUANTITY','UNBLENDED_COST'],
    Granularity='MONTHLY',
    Filter={
        'Dimensions': {
            'Key':'USAGE_TYPE_GROUP',
            'Values': ['EC2: EBS - Snapshots']
        }
    }
)
```

This gives me the cost. But this is the total cost for the snapshot usage, i.e. for all the volumes. Is there any way to filter based on tags on the snapshot?

I tries adding the fallowing Filter:

```
Filter={
    'And': [
        {
            'Dimensions': {
               'Key':'USAGE_TYPE_GROUP',
               'Values': ['EC2: EBS - Snapshots']
            }
        },
        {
            'Tags':{
                'Key': 'test',
                'Values': ['aj']
        } 
    }
]
}
```

There is 1 snapshot where I have added that tag. I checked the date range and the snapshot was created within that time range and is still available. I tried changing granularity to `DAILY` too.

But this always shows 0 cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Tags'` can be added in your filter as follows:

```
response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={
        'Start': '2019-01-10',
        'End': '2019-01-15'
    },
    Metrics=['BLENDED_COST','USAGE_QUANTITY','UNBLENDED_COST'],
    Granularity='MONTHLY',
    Filter={
        'Dimensions': {
            'Key':'USAGE_TYPE',
            'Values': ['APN1-EBS:SnapshotUsage']
         },
         'Tags': {
             'Key': 'keyName',
             'Values': [
                 'keyValue',
              ]
         }
     }
)
```

You can find the exact usage in the [boto3 cost explorer API reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage).

You could also group by tag keys like this:

```
Filter={
    'Dimensions': {
        'Key':'USAGE_TYPE',
        'Values': ['APN1-EBS:SnapshotUsage']
     }
 },
 GroupBy=[
    {
        'Type': 'DIMENSION'|'TAG',
        'Key': 'string'
    },
],
```

It won't filter out tags, but it will group the returned data by tag key.  This will return ALL tag values matching the tag key, so it may be too broad, but you can use it to troubleshoot any additional problems.

I'd confirm that your tag values and keys all match up.

Comment: Thanks.I tried that. (code updated in the question). But does that really filter on snapshot tags? It always returns 0 as cost.

Comment: @aaj That should work. [Here's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsage.html) the AWS GetCostAndUsage API docs that offer some clarification.  Drill down on tags.  I added another method to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi, can I filter my cost by more than 1 tag? from the docs its seems that I cant...

Comment: Are you sure that this sample of code works?. The documentation of AWS said that: 

"Because each Expression can have only one operator, the service returns an error if more than one is specified. The following example shows an Expression object that creates an error."

Answer (score 2):

To query the snapshots or even other services using tags, you need to activate them in the billing menu.
Refer the link to activate the tags you need to query:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=us-east-1#/preferences/tags

NOTE: Only master accounts in an organization and single accounts that are not members of an organization have access to the Cost Allocation Tags.

I hope that helps!